# Split a panda column into text and numbers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to split a column based on type.  I want to show numbers separate from text.

I have tried to add it without a loop, but the shape is different.  I therefore resorted to loop it through.  It is however only giving me the last number in all fields

Python input:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
newdf['name'] = ('leon','eurika','monica','wian')
newdf['surname'] = ('swart38','39swart','11swart','swart10')
a = newdf.shape[0]

newdf['age'] = ""
for i in range (0,a):
    newdf['age'] =  re.sub(r'\D', "",str(newdf.iloc[i,1]))

print (newdf)
```

I am expecting the age column to show `38,39,11,10`.  The answer is however all `"10"` being the last field.

Out:

```
     name  surname age
0    leon  swart38  10
1  eurika  swart39  10
2  monica  11swart  10
3    wian  swart10  10
```

Comment: your code would work (although it would not be very performant because of the for loop) had you replaced `newdf['age']` with `newdf.loc[i, 'age']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are assigning new values to `newdf['age']` in every iteration of the `for` loop, in which the last assignment was `10`.

You can fix it by indexing:

```
a = newdf.shape[0]
newdf['age'] = ""
for i in range (0,a):
    newdf['age'][i] =  re.sub(r'\D', "",str(newdf.iloc[i,1]))
    #           ^^^
```

Or instead, use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
newdf['age'] = newdf['surname'].str.extract('(\d+)')
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
     name  surname age
0    leon  swart38  38
1  eurika  39swart  39
2  monica  11swart  11
3    wian  swart10  10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Series.str.replace`:

```
newdf['age'] = newdf['surname'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')
```